# Why do I lose my coins when I quit?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

Every time I quit Jetpack Joyride and start it up again, I have 2659 or so coins, even if I had 20 000 when I quit playing. Is there a way to make this not happen?

Comment: Could you specify a platform?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug with the game. According to [this forum post](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showthread.php?p=1900731#post1900731), this issue only occurs if you quit and then start the game again in a short period of time. Try waiting a longer period of time, such as 10-15 minutes, as the post recommends.

Answer (score 0):

If this keeps happening, delete the game and re-download it. You get all your stuff back after one game, and bugs are removed for four days, then they come back.